# Calculating the mean "whereabout" of a joystick

Tags: r, geometry, data-analysis

I have recently collected data using the NASA TLX tool, which includes a tracking task, where subjects have to keep the joystick deadcenter while having to react to multiple tasks.

The raw data looks somewhat like this:

```
                    V2                      V5   V6
1   9:10:32.799614  TRACK   STATE   CURSOR  X   -0.005495149786872552                                                   
2   09:10:32.801598 TRACK   STATE   CURSOR  Y   0.11168536804754137                                                 
3   09:10:32.805621 TRACK   STATE   CURSOR  X   -0.005616917142611262                                                   
4   09:10:32.807115 TRACK   STATE   CURSOR  Y   0.11102381417330846
```

The x-coordinate shows how far off the subject was on the x-coordinate, whereas y shows the y-axis.

Now for my analysis I decided to use

```
  df_track <- df_all %>%
  filter(V2 == "TRACK") %>%
  group_by(Proband, Teil, V5) #%>% 
  summarise(Precisetrack = median(abs(as.numeric(V6)), na.rm = T)) 

  for (i in 1:nrow(df_track)) {if(i %% 2!=1) {
  df_track$Avgs[i]<-
                     (df_track$Precisetrack[i]+df_track$Precisetrack[i-1])/2
    }
  }
```

While reviewing my code and reviewing my results I stumbled across the geometric mean, and some controversy on whether I should use a median or a mean. Is there anyone who maybe could give me some insight into whether my analysis is somewhat valid?

Comment: Discussion of whether or not you should use median or a mean really isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help choosing methods for your analysis, you should instead ask at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for the suggested edit, as well as the reference to cross validated!